# adding a time stamp to the file name using php

Tags: php

I need to rename files uploaded to  server using php and add a timestamp on the file. I have written a code and its showing this eg: `logicgates.docx-29-Aug-2018 19-55-36.docx`
instead of : `logicgates-29-Aug-2018 19-55-36.docx` without the file extension in the middle of the filename.

```
<?php

session_start();

date_default_timezone_set('Africa/Harare');

$date = date("d-M-Y H-i-s");
//$time = time("h-i-sa");


$targetfolder = "uploads/";

$allowedMimes = ['application/pdf','application/msword','text/plain','application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document',];

$targetfolder = $targetfolder . basename( $_FILES['file']['name']) ;

$type=pathinfo($targetfolder,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

 $ok=1;

$file_type=$_FILES['file']['type'];


if  (in_array($_FILES['file']['type'], $allowedMimes))

 {

 if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $targetfolder))

 {
    //add date and time stamp to the uploaded file 

    if (file_exists($file_type))
    {
        $_SESSION['message']= "Sorry, file already exists. Please rename if you still want to upload it.";
    header("location:lecsubmit?error") ;
    }

 else{
    rename("uploads/".$_FILES['file']['name'],"uploads/".$_FILES['file']['name']."-".$date.".".$type);
  $_SESSION['message'] ="The file ". basename( $_FILES["file"]["name"]). " submitted successfully.";

       header("location:lecsubmit?done") ;
    } 

}

 else {

   $_SESSION['message']= "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
    header("location:lecsubmit?error") ;

 }

}

else {


  $_SESSION['message']= "You may only upload PDFs, DOCXs, DOCs or TXT files..";
    header("location:lecsubmit?error") ;
}
?>
```

Comment: Use only `time()` function.

Comment: Clearly `$_FILES['file']['name']` contains the full file name with the file extension. Instead of using `$_FILES['file']['name']`, take its value, remove the extension, and add the date to the end, then put the extension back.

Comment: at @JohnConde it would have been better if you had shown the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the last dot ".", cut the left part, add timestamp and add the right part:

```
$file = "uploads/" . $_FILES['file']['name'];
$lastDot = strrpos($file, '.');
$newFile = substr($file, 0, $lastDot) . "-$date." . substr($file, $lastDot + 1);

rename($file, $newFile);
```

**EDIT:**
Changed *str_replace* by *strrpos* aproach suggested by @Elementary.

Comment: This is a really bad way to proceed eg doc.123manuel.doc will be 123manuel.is it what the op want ?

Comment: nope, look better, I´m replacing ".doc", not just "doc".

Comment: but if the name of the file is "my.document.doc" the result will be "myument.timestamp.doc", this will be wrong

Comment: So you can upvote my answer and edit yours in order to fit requirement. You can use str_replace but you need to specify the last occurrence of dot as offset to start replacement.

Answer (score 0):

you can remove the extension first:

```
 rename("uploads/".$_FILES['file']['name'],"uploads/".substr($_FILES['file']['name'],0,strrpos($_FILES['file']['name'],'.'))."-".$date.".".$type);
```

Comment: this is wrong, if the file name contains any dots, like "my.file.doc" the result will be "my.timestamp.doc" instead of "my.file.timestamp.doc"

Comment: I look only for the last occurrence of the dot. You must learn more about strrpos. Yours will replace any occurence of type in the filename and is wrong. Eg doc.doxit.doc will be transform to .doxit

Comment: I don´t see the additional "r" on you strrpos, sorry, you are right